# android how to call onactivityresult with tabhost activity?

Tags: android

i am using tabs at bottom on all screens.,and i am using onactivityresult() method for selecting image from gallery and camera.my code is working without tab activity.,but when i am using my code with tabactivity its not working,i am searching from 2 days ,but no solution is getting.,what i do.., i am so frusted from this,please help me..,thankyou.here is onactivityresult()method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode ==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
            String imagepath= getpath(chosenImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            customImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false));
            Constant._profilePicBase64=Constant.convertBitmapToBase64(bitmap);
            getprofilepic();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Unable to get Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (resultCode ==RESULT_OK)
        {
            try{
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                customImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false));

                Constant._profilePicBase64=Constant.convertBitmapToBase64(bitmap);
                getprofilepic();

            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Unable to get Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but anyway this is the answer:

your onActivityResult should be placed in the TabActivity group

and your startActivityForResult should be called referring to the parent Activity

**example:**

```
TabActivityGroup parentActivity = (TabActivityGroup) getParent();
Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

parentActivity.startActivityForResult(gallery, IMAGE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Comment: thnaku..but i have got solution...:)

Comment: So why don't you post it instead of: 1.leaving the question unanswered and 2.Not accepting @beginner1 answer?